# How to run bash script in vagrant from under sudo su -?

Tags: php, bash, shell, vagrant

I get into the vagrant shell and then go under sudo su - in my project. Next I have to go to the folder with the command cd /var/www/html and execute the command to generate documents, let it be generate_document. But the problem is that if I write a bash script on all these actions, I stop in the vagrant shell

I tried the command and a few lines in the file, but not one action has helped me.

How can I write a bash script that:

- comes into vagrant with the command 'vagrant ssh my_crm'
- performs input under 'sudo su -'
- goes into the folder 'cd /var/www/html/'
- executes 'generate_document'

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/Desktop/Work/arteccrm/vagrant

first variant
vagrant ssh my_crm -c " sudo su -; cd /var/www/html/; generate_document"

another variant
sudo-s -- "vagrant ssh my_crm; cd /var/www/html/; generate_document"

another variant
vagrant ssh my_crm -c 'sudo su -' && ssh my_crm -c ' cd /var/www/html/; generate_document'

another variant
vagrant ssh my_crm -c 'sudo su - && cd /var/www/html/ && generate_document'

another variant
vagrant ssh my_crm -c 'sudo su -'
vagrant ssh my_crm -c 'cd /var/www/html/'
vagrant ssh my_crm -c 'generate_document'

another variant
vagrant ssh crm -c 'cd /var/www/html/'
vagrant ssh crm -c 'cd /var/www/html/'
cd /var/www/html/ && generate_document
```

Comment: For more information on how to correctly pass parameters, you can see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh.html and http://qaru.site/questions/53216/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution my problem:

vagrant ssh crm -c 'sudo sh -c "cd /var/www/html/; generate_document"'